# how can i catch currently playing media player instance in fragment on android

Tags: android, android-fragments, instance, android-mediaplayer

how can i catch currently playing media player instance in fragment when come back to again fragment on android.

I want to stop currently playing music and start new music with new link.

Comment: How do you want to use it ? Show code

Comment: Try passing the `MediaPlayer` or an instance capable of manipulating the `MediaPlayer` via a `Bundle`.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.